# Quickly remove tuples that contain tuples of other list

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, subset, data-transform

I would like to remove all the tuples in List A that contain a tuple in List B.

This is normally a trivial matter, but I have 10 million records in List A and 200K in List B. My current script (see below) is very slow (~10 seconds for each scan of List A).

Example:

```
# Input:
listA = [(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,4,5,6),(1,2,3,7,55),(8,21,22,24,37),...]  # 10 million records
listB = [(1,2,4),(1,4,6),(21,24,37),...]  # 200K records

# Desired Output (filtered listA):
listA = [(1,2,3,7,55),...]
```

Current script that is slow:

```
listA=[(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,4,5,6),(1,2,3,7,55),(8,21,22,24,37)]
listB=[(1,2,4),(1,4,6),(21,24,37)]
listATemp=[]

for b in listB:
  for a in listA:
    if not set(b).issubset(a) :
      listATemp.append(a)
  listA= listATemp
  listATemp= []
```

Comment: Are the items in elements of A always unique? Are the elements of B always three-tuples? Optimising this is going to depend on the specific constraints and preconditions.

Comment: Yes, elements in both lists are unique. Yes, elements of B are always three-tuples. Note my real-life example has 5-tuples in list B and 7-tuples in list A, but I simplified it here to make it easier to understand. Also, thank you for the edit.

Comment: Are the tuples in listA and listB always both ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.combinations` and `frozenset`:

```
setB = set(map(frozenset, listB))
n = len(listB[0])
listA = [a for a in listA if not any(frozenset(c) in setB for c in combinations(a, n))]
```

Or assuming every tuple is sorted (if not, you could of course sort them first):

```
setB = set(listB)
n = len(listB[0])
listA = [a for a in listA if setB.isdisjoint(combinations(a, n))]
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind - if the OP's tuples are really sorted, the frozensets aren't needed.

Comment: @superb rain - Well done! Thank you! :) What would have taken days to run now finishes in a couple of minutes!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right. Added a version for that.

Comment: @FirstRedPepper Just added another, might be a bit faster.

Comment: I suspect that keeping `any` would be more efficient than the disjoint - `any(c in setB for c in combinations(a, n))`. @FirstRedPepper the total speedup is `O(len(listA) * len(listB))` -> `O(len(listA))`, so pretty substantial, plus the savings on a bunch of list resizes from using a list comprehension instead of appending to an initially empty list.

Comment: You both are fantastic - thank you. Could either of you explain why this approach runs so much faster than my original script with for loops?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why would `any` be faster? I think `isdisjoint` does the same thing as `not any(...)`, but at C speed: [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c3270939c09e4c8e80fd26449b718a998701912/Objects/setobject.c#L1352-L1374).

Comment: @superbrain I thought it consumed the iterable to a set; if not, then it won't make a difference.

Comment: @FirstRedPepper Mostly the much better complexity class, see jon's comment above.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I think `issuperset` for example [does that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c3270939c09e4c8e80fd26449b718a998701912/Objects/setobject.c#L1724-L1737), and I don't like it...

Comment: Very clever - thank you! I'm still wrapping my head around it - in English script the script loops through each record of A and checks that it is not in list B considering each of its elements combinations. Correct?

Comment: @FirstRedPepper Yes (although not list B but set B, and only the combinations of the needed size).